# Освобождение памяти из под динамического массива (с++)

Tags: c++

Если динамический массив создается (через `new`) внутри какого-то блока кода, например, внутри `if`, то освобождение памяти через `delete` нужно производить внутри этого же блока?

```
if (count != 0)
{
    int *masPos = new int[count];
    int *masNeg = new int[n - count];

    //...

    delete [] masPos;
    delete [] masNeg;
}
```

Comment: @ims а почему вы сами не попробуете? Если вы задаете этот вопрос, то, надо полагать, что вы по какой-то причине не пробовали вынести ваши delete[] за пределы if, иначе бы увидели, что компилятор ругается на необъявленные идентификаторы (это, кстати, ответ на ваш вопрос)

Comment: удалять можно там где хочется/нужно. другое дело, нужно иметь указатель на удаляемый массив и собственно сам созданный массив.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это не имеет принципиального значения.

```
int *masPos = NULL;
if (something) {
    masPos = new int[10];
}

...

if (masPos) {
    delete [] massPos;
}
```

Как правильно заметили выше, нужен только указатель на массив

Comment: @Dmitry Lepeshkin ок, ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

> Если динамический массив создается (через new) внутри какого-то блока кода, например, внутри if, то освобождение памяти через delete нужно производить внутри этого же блока?

Нет конечно же. И в этом вся "соль" использования динамической памяти (не вся соль, я вру, но часть истины в этом выражении имеется). 
Вы сами определяете когда вам нужно удалить либо создать определенный объект, вы вручную (либо же автоматически, по заданному условию) можете управлять его временем жизни.  Одним словом, время жизни объекта, выделенного и *сконструированного* при помощи вызова *new* определяется только вами, как программистом.
Обратите внимание, сконструированного, ибо сишная функция *malloc* только аллоцирует (выделяет) память под объект (переменную), но не производит конструирования объекта.

По выходу за пределы блока никакого автоматического удаления и деструкции объекта не произойдет, если, правда, конечно, вы не используете smart ptr'ы, но это уже совсем другая история.

А вот объектам и типам, создаваемым в стеке, к сожалению, жить можно только в пределах блока {}. Плюс, стек (кадр стека), как правило, имеет ограниченный, и зачастую небольшой объем (зависит от настроек ОС ибо же вручную определяется программистом), что тоже может служить ограничением.

Comment: Разве операция `new` тоже не только выделяет память под объект?

Comment: @ims, нет, еще вызывает конструктор. В случае new[] -- конструктор без параметров.